# Why the code is not taking the specified number of elements in the ArrayList?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
        ArrayList<String> arr= new ArrayList();
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the array");
        int temp= sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the elements in the array");

        String num;
        for(int i=0; i<temp; i++) {
            num= sc.nextLine();
            arr.add(num);
            //System.out.println("i= "+ i +"temp= "+temp);  
        }
```

The problem is that if i want to add 5 elements it is taking the first element as null and only letting me to input rest 4 elements but i want to enter all the 5 numbers. Where is the problem?

Comment: add `sc.nextLine();` just before the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> arr= new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the array");
        int temp= sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the elements in the array");

        String num;
        sc.nextLine(); //add this it should work !
        for(int i=0; i<temp; i++) {
            num= sc.nextLine();
            arr.add(num);
            //System.out.println("i= "+ i +"temp= "+temp);  
        }
```

Reason --
"You need to move the sc pointer to the next line after taking the first input, your pointer is looking for the first integer on the same line instead of the one below it"